# modal panel in sencha doesnt show up on click

Tags: extjs, touch, modal-dialog, panel

I want to display a modal info window by clicking a button in a toolbar. I dont know why, but nothing happens when i click the button.

heres my code:

```
xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'bottom',
            items: [
                {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Infos anzeigen',
                handler: function(){
                    var panel = new Ext.Panel({
                        modal: true,
                        left: 0,
                        top: 0,
                        width: 220,
                        height: 356,
                        layout: 'fit',
                        html: 'Testing'
                    });
                    panel.show();
                    }
                }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for an [Ext.Window](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window):

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
    modal: true,
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 220,
    height: 356,
    layout: 'fit',
    html: 'Testing'
});
win.show();
```